# Replace text in a PDF with an image

Tags: c#, image, pdf

I'd like to read through a PDF to locate a certain keyword, in this case something like [SIGNATURE]. Then, I'd like to replace [SIGNATURE] with an image of someone's signature and save this new version of the document as a new PDF. Is this possible using C#? Since many different document types might be used, it's not possible for me to just hard code a position for the signature.

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Have you tried it?

Comment: Have you checked iTextSharp? If a sentence starts as C# and continues with PDF, it usually ends with iTextSharp.

Answer (score 2):

Use [iTextSharp](https://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/).  Failing that, you're looking at trying to manage this with Crystal Reports, which is no fun for anyone.